# Global variable loses value outside loop

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script to extract data from BLOBs in a SQL database. The extraction process works great. I want to add some sort of progress indication to the script. I have a total record count from a SQL query, and an incremental counter that increases for each file exported. The incremental counter works, but the total record count - which I attempted to assign to a global variable - does not seem to hold its value. Am I declaring it incorrectly?

```
## Export of "larger" Sql Server Blob to file            
## with GetBytes-Stream.         
# Configuration data     
$StartTime = Get-Date
$Server = "server";
$UserID = "user";
$Password = "password";
$Database = "db";
$Dest = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test\";
$bufferSize = 8192; 

# Counts total rows
$CountSql = "SELECT Count(extension) as countall from 
                (
                    SELECT  p.[people_id], right(pi.[file_name],4) as extension
                    FROM dbo.pictures as pi 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.people AS p ON p.person_picture = pi.pictures_id
                    where left([image_type], 5) = 'image'
                ) as countall"

# Selects Data
$Sql = "SELECT p.[people_id], pi.[image_file], right(pi.[file_name],4), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY people_id) as count
        FROM dbo.pictures as pi 
        INNER JOIN dbo.people AS p ON p.person_picture = pi.pictures_id
        where left([image_type], 5) = 'image'";    

# Open ADO.NET Connection            
$con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;            
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;" +             
                        "Integrated Security=False;" + 
                        "User ID=$UserID;" +
                        "Password=$Password;" +           
                        "Initial Catalog=$Database";            
$con.Open();            

# New Command and Reader for total row count
$CountCmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $CountSql, $con;
$crd = $CountCmd.ExecuteReader();
While ($crd.Read())
{
    $crd.GetValue($global:1)
}
$crd.Close();

# New Command and Reader for rest of data     
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $Sql, $con;            
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader();            

# Create a byte array for the stream.            
$out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize)            

# Looping through records
While ($rd.Read())            
{            
    $total = $global:1
    $counter = ($rd.GetValue(3));
    Write-Output ("Exporting $counter of $total`: {0}" -f $rd.GetGUID(0));

    # New BinaryWriter            
    $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($Dest + $rd.GetGUID(0) + $rd.GetString(2)), Create, Write;            
    $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs;            

    $start = 0;            
    # Read first byte stream            
    $received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);            
    While ($received -gt 0)            
    {            
       $bw.Write($out, 0, $received);            
       $bw.Flush();            
       $start += $received;            
       # Read next byte stream            
       $received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);            
    }            

    $bw.Close();            
    $fs.Close();            
}            

# Closing & Disposing all objects            
$fs.Dispose();            
$rd.Close();            
$cmd.Dispose();            
$con.Close();            
$EndTime = Get-Date
$TotalTime = $EndTime - $StartTime    
Write-Host ("Finished in {0:g}" -f $TotalTime)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PS C:\Users\me> C:\Scripts\ExportImagesFromNTST.ps1
21380
Exporting 1 of : 3089b464-e667-4bf4-80b3-0002d582d4fa
Exporting 2 of : 04cf7738-ae19-4771-92b8-0003c5f27947
Exporting 3 of : 94485b5d-fe71-438d-a097-000ad185c915
```

and so on. 21380 should be $1 which should also be $total.

Comment: Nowhere in your script you assign something to `$global:1`, and `$total` only assigned from that variable with unknown value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think PetSerAl hit the nail on the head here. You create a [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object (`$CountCmd`), and from that create a [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) (`$crd`), and then tell `$crd` to use the `GetValue()` method that accepts an integer as a parameter, so that it knows which column to return the value of, but you reference a global variable with a name of '1', which is never defined, so you effectively pass `$null` to that method, so it doesn't get any value. I'm honestly surprised that it doesn't throw errors at you right there. You would probably want to just pass the integer 1 as the argument for that method, and assign it to `$Total` in the `While` loop. I'm honestly guessing here, but from what I see I think it should be:

```psh
$crd = $CountCmd.ExecuteReader();
While ($crd.Read())
{
    $Total = $crd.GetValue(0)
}
$crd.Close();
```

I'm pretty sure that will assign the value of the first column (which for that sql command should just be 1 row with 1 column, right? Just the total count?), anyway, assign the first column's value for the current row to `$Total`. Then later you can reference `$Total` just fine to update your progress.

You sir, need to look into the `write-progress` cmdlet if you want to track progress, it's perfect for your script.

Comment: The index would be 0 for the first column, not 1. But I used that and it worked perfectly! I am still getting my scripting legs under me - thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, my SQL-fu is weak, sorry about that. Glad you got it working, and I'll update the answer to show the correct code.

Comment: And I took your advice and used write-progress! It's awesome! http://i.imgur.com/T9V0IkA.png